# WPF close secondary window before main window

Tags: wpf

I have 2 windows in a WPF application, and If I close the Main one, I want to close the other too.

I achieved this by setting in my App.xaml:

```
ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose"
```

The 2 windows have a `Window_Closing` event in which I de-initialise some components. Now what I want to achieve is: if I close the MainWindow, the `Window_Closing` event of the second window must execute before the closing event of the Main one, because the de-init of the second one has to be executed before the first. Any idea on how can I achive this?

Comment: I removed the tag "MVVM". This question has nothing to do with that, it's just about the behavior of UI elements (in this case the windows of WPF). The separation of the app in different layers or the existance of ViewModels simply don't matter here.

Comment: yes you are right, I was following the MVVM pattern but the question was encapsulated to a more "generic" issue I had. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Application.Current.Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.windows(v=vs.110).aspx) collection. It contains the list of all the windows of your app; you can iterate through them and operate on them.

In this case, you can write:

```
public void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Window w in Application.Current.Windows)
    {
        if (w.Title == "Secondary Window") // <-- or whatever check you want to identify the secondary Window
        {
            w.Close();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to gain a flexible behavior, for example you can close ALL the secondary windows, not just one.

Comment: it looks like I cannot close/change visibility of windows while window is closing:  "Cannot set Visibility to Visible or call Show, ShowDialog, Close, or WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle while a Window is closing."

Comment: @berthos I don't get such an error... maybe in the Closing of the MainWindow you are closing also that window itself.

Answer (score 1):

Could you simply call the Close() function of the second window from the main window Window_Closing event?

```
void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    secondaryWindow.Close();

    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is an idea, but I was thinking for a more dynamic way, this also could work if I iterate all this windows in a foreach statement

Answer (score 1):

Close all windows but the `MainWindow` in the `Closing` event handler. This should work:

```
void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Window w in Application.Current.Windows)
    {
        if (w != this)
            w.Close();
    }

    //handle clean up for MainWindow here...
}
```

You might also want to consider to handle the `Application.Current.Exit` event to perform the cleanup of all windows in one place.